# Override spring-boot EurekaInstanceConfigBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I am building a dockerized spring-cloud based microservice that registers with eureka. Part of the registration process is asking the host for the port mapped to the container so docker can choose a free host port for the containerized service.

I have a host based service the dockerized service can ask for the port mapping and am now trying to register the microservice with eureka using the external port.

I get the right port inside my microservice but am unable to override the `EurekaInstanceConfig`.

What i have tried:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class ApplicationBootstrapper {

    @Value("${containerIp}")
    private String containerIp;

    @Bean
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfigBean() {
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean();
        String hostPort = new RestTemplate().getForObject(
            "http://{hostname}:7691/container/{id}/hostPort", 
            String.class, 
            containerIp, 
            config.getHostname());

        config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
        config.setIpAddress(containerIp);
        config.setNonSecurePort(Integer.valueOf(hostPort));

        return config;
}
```

My custom `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` gets created but the configuration is not picked up (the service registers with its internal container port).

The question is: How do i override the `EurekaInstanceConfigBean`?

**EDIT (2):**

As Steve pointed out and now as spring-cloud-1.0.0.RELEASE is available most of my previous solution is now obsolete. I've attached my final solution in case anyone is trying something similar:

```
@Configuration
public class EurekaConfig {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(EurekaConfig.class);

    @Value("${containerIp}")
    private String containerIp;

    @Value("${kompositPort:7691}")
    private String kompositPort;

    @Bean
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfigBean() {
        Integer hostPort = new RestTemplate().getForObject(
            "http://{containerIp}:{port}/container/{instanceId}/hostPort",
            Integer.class, 
            containerIp, 
            kompositPort, 
            getHostname());

        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean();
        config.setNonSecurePort(hostPort);
        config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
        config.setIpAddress(containerIp);
        config.getMetadataMap().put("instanceId", getHostname());
        return config;
    }

    private static String getHostname() {
        String hostname = null;
        try {
            hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            logger.error("Cannot get host info", e);
        }
        return hostname;
    }

}
```

Comment: `@AutoConfigureBefore` has no effect in a user-config class unless you are actually registering autoconfig. Is that what you are doing? If so then you should update the question because it is significant. If not then the solution you have is verbose and mostly unnecessary.

Comment: @Dave Could you elaborate on that? My first try (source before the edit) didn't work. My Eureka instance config bean has been created but not used. My intention with the part after the edit was to create an `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` **before** the spring-cloud provided bean has been created. At least it works now - so, could you maybe give me a  hint what part of my solution is unnecessary so i could improve it?

Comment: Are you using snapshots? I think the change that Steve is referring to below is relevant. Your bean is being used, but the port is being rebound to it after initialization.

Comment: @DaveSyer I'm using RC3. Since the change Steve is referring to is more or less what i have done in my code i think you are right. I'll give snap a try and come back on this.

Comment: @DaveSyer I've tried with 1.0.0.RELEASE now. Works perfect. Thanks for the fantastic work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed [only 6 days ago](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/225). Prior to that fix, whatever you set for nonSecurePort will be overridden with `${server.port}`. My suggestion, which is kind of hacky but what can you do when working with pre-release libraries, is to subclass `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` and implement `InitializingBean`, so you can set the port in `afterPropertiesSet()`.

Comment: I'm unsure if this is really the problem here. As you can see from my posted code i'm already constructing my own `EurekaInstanceConfigBean`. The problem seems to be that my bean isn't picked up in the autoconfig process. (Side note: I'm not using sidecar).

Comment: Kinda late now, but the reason is that `@Value` is processed after a bean is returned from a `@Bean` method. So it didn't matter what you do when creating the bean, nonSecurePort would get overwritten during post-processing. `afterPropertiesSet()` gets called after post-processing, which is what my suggested workaround took advantage of.